# Bar Chart on Iphone

Tags: iphone, charts

I'm looking for a free charting library for iphone. I need to draw a simple bar Chart. 
Do you know one?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone

Answer (score 6):

this one may help you

> [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) is a plotting framework for
>   Mac OS X and iPhone OS. It provides 2D
>   visualization of data, and is tightly
>   integrated with Apple technologies
>   like Core Animation, Core Data, and
>   Cocoa Bindings.

Comment: I tryed to use CorePlot (following this tutorial : http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application ) but it needed the 2.2.1 sdk version that I don't have. Do I take the wrong version of CorePlot, or is there a way to get the 2.2.1 sdk version?

Comment: @Raphael Pinto - That tutorial is terribly out of date.  If you download the framework, there are a few sample applications that come with it and demonstrate the use of the framework.  These can be compiled without problem on iPhone OS 3.x.