# Which library this app using?

Tags: iphone, charts

I would like to do some functionality like this app for iphone:

http://www.ezraschartbooks.com/Site/Home.html

I would like to draw chart, navigate and interact on the chart, scale, zoom, etc... such as scale the chart by interact with the y-axis or x-axis.

Can anyone know which library that app using? Or would you please suggest me some library can do that functionality. I have tried Core-Plot but this library does not support scaling chart by interacting with axis.

any suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that they're using a customized version of [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).

**Update**: Check out [Is there a good charting library for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone) for various iPhone charting implementations.