# 2D charts on iphone

Tags: iphone

Is there any API for drawing charts on iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is: [s7vengraphview](http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in API. I was looking for the same some time ago and found this [Blog Post](http://pmougin.wordpress.com/2007/12/10/google-chart-api-fun-with-cocoa-and-f-script/) very helpful. It descripes the use of the Google Chart API.

Maybe you also can use one of the following (not tested):

SM2DGraphView

Narrative -- Cocoa Plotting Framework (alpha state)

Answer (score 0):

There is no chart drawing API built into the iPhone OS or SDK.

However, Apple's Accelerometer example app contains 2D chart drawing code that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library called [PowerPlot](http://powerplot.nua-schroers.de) which is available under a dual-license model.

There are other alternatives, one frequently mentioned choice being [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot), see also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone/4713851#4713851) for further discussion.