# How can I create better looking charts than those generated by Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, graph, plot, charts, core-plot

I'm looking for good library for iphone to draw charts (pie chart, bar chart). I've tested Core plot, which was recommended by many people, but I think the generated charts look poor.

I saw example of good-looking charts in that application:
[image]

Anyone knows what library was used there? Or what library can help me achieve similar, nice look?

Comment: another example of nice bar chart: http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/015/Purple/ca/2b/5d/mzl.fxjzjxtb.320x480-75.jpg

Comment: I used Core-Plot in one of my apps, and it was easy enough to use, but I have to agree that it isn't the prettiest.

Comment: Dont confuse the chart with the surroundings. You can put a gradient behind any view.  Core-Plot is capable of things like this.

Comment: Core Plot is highly customizable.  Both of those charts can be made (and possibly were) using that framework.  Just because the default charts in the sample applications weren't to your liking doesn't mean that's all you can do with the framework.  Look through the highly customized charts in some of the applications using the framework, for example: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/AppsUsingCorePlot

Answer (score 1):

I would use CorePlot, but since you dont like it…

In one project I used the [Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) api.  Nearly everything is customizable, the only downside is that you have to be connected the internet to fetch the image.  Depending on your use case, it might be appealing.

You can also checkout the huge list of responses to this similar question: [Is there a good charting library for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone)