# How to draw a nice bar graph on iOS (iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad

I want to draw a good looking bar graph and thought Core plot could come to the rescue, but the bar graphs in the examples look like they were drawn in MSPaint...

I want each bar to have two colors, split in the middle vertically.

Is this possible to do in Core plot or are there better suited libraries?

I've previously used libraries like MS Chart Controls (ASP.NET): 
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart where they have great bar chart controls...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create better looking charts than those generated by Core Plot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410989/how-can-i-create-better-looking-charts-than-those-generated-by-core-plot)

Comment: As I note there, the display of a Core Plot bar chart is completely customizable, from line width to spacing to the use of gradients.  I'm sorry that the examples were not up to your standards, but that's all they are supposed to be: examples to start from.  You can make things a lot more visually appealing than those samples, but to be honest I don't think I could draw something as good as the default in Microsoft Paint.  My skills there topped out at making stick figures.

Comment: Sure, but examples are often used to glorify the library :-) I was just a bit disappointed by the bar charts I found and googling for other examples of bar charts in Core Plot just got me even worse looking graphs that I am positive you could have outdone in 2 minutes ;-)

Comment: The examples might reflect what happens when you have engineers working on something without the aid of designers.  Unfortunately, they end up being templates for people who just copy and paste code in order to roll something out quickly.  If you have a chart look in mind that you could Photoshop together and ask how to create it in Core Plot (here or on the mailing list), I'm sure someone could show how to replicate that using the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chart Tools
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Comment: I need the offline mode, sorry for not specifying this