# Draw graph on iPhone with something easier then Core Plot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I need to draw one simple graph in my app. I tried to make it with Core Plot, but I can't even import it in my project properly. Is there any more simple but still pretty framework?

Comment: Did you following the importing instructions 100%?

Comment: I'm not shure, but I tried to. It seems not to work with new Xcode and ARC.

Comment: You can turn off ARC for specific files.

Comment: The 1.0 release does not work under Xcode 4.4, but the [latest development version](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/checkout) does. To stay compatible with older systems, Core Plot does not use ARC, but it can be used in projects that do.

Answer (score 3):

You can following link show the plot chart with examples [Here](http://bit.ly/NX5qWh)

Also here that type of the question aries which is below.

1)[Core plot chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410989/how-can-i-create-better-looking-charts-than-those-generated-by-core-plot)

2)[Library available into IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone)

This may helping to lot and decide you which is the better for you implementation is easy.