# How can we plot charts dynamically in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, charts

In my iPhone app, I need to plot the charts dynamically based on the data that comes from my database.

How can I make the charts and display them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good charting library for iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a good charting library for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your chart should be as simple enough you can try the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). Where the chart will be fetched via web. Or you can go for [core plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)

See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone)