# how to draw stacked bar chart on iphone, is there api to do it?

Tags: iphone, charts, stacked

Hi  How to draw stacked bar chart on iphone, is there api can achieve it? not core plot, it's too big. I want to look for a small open source project can do this. :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it compares in size to corePlot but MIMChart looks promising.

http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/08/iphoneipad-chart-librarymimchartlib.html

Others are covered in this SO post:

[Is there a good charting library for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone)

Outside of that, you're likely in custom drawing your own.