# iOS: draw editable Graphs in iPad App, using html5

Tags: ios, html, graph

In my App I need to draw graph data with different datamodels that frequently change and can not be generalized. This graph data must be editable with a slider or a segmented control.

The idea is to load all necessary data to draw the graph from the server. Is html5 the right solution? Can the iPad-UI-Controlls used to manipulate the graph?

Where do I start and how much work is it?

Currently I'm using Core Plot to draw the graph - but I need to model my graph data on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: If you are developing for Android as well or you are better at javascript, then you can use HTML5.0. Have a look at http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/charts/

Option 2: If you want to develop it natively for iPad(which I feel is a better option), then please look at google library for graph http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/ and [Is there a good charting library for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I extended the work of this gentleman:

http://buildmobile.com/creating-a-graph-with-quartz-2d/#fbid=EKAB22zV7It

And I'm quite pleased with the results. It took me about a week to get my graph able to draw a stock chart with scrolling, pinching zooming, 3 different symbol indicators, a secondary plot line, tap-able data points with a little custom popover showing details, and a few annotations. Not bad considering the overall complexity, and largely thanks to the detailed walkthrough.

He also talks about why he didn't use Core Plot.

Good luck,

Damien