# Display charts on iPhone and mobile devices

Tags: ios, cordova, charts, google-visualization

I have an iOS app which currently uses Google Charts to display some data on a chart. I've seen that as April 2015 Google Image Charts will be deprecated and won't be usable. Is there any other way of displaying charts?

This app also has a counterpart for mobile devices (Symbian, BlackBerry, Bada, etc.) so it'd be cool if this service works also for this devices.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone

Comment: That could make for the iOS app, but is there any service like Google Image Charts which could be used both on iOS and Phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [DSBarChart](http://dhilipsiva.com/DSBarChart/). A simple Objective-C Bar Chart / Histogram library.

And here is the [sample usage](http://dhilipsiva.com/DSBarChart#sample-usage)

Precisely what you are looking for.